# How to configure a consumer to external queue (another application) with MassTransit

Tags: masstransit

I have a publisher in one application, that publishes a message with an specific message type.
This message will be consumed by another application (both using MassTransit) and I'm getting the message skipped.
I think the problem is the message type config in the envelope.

The question is: How can I configure my consumer to accept a specific message type?
I don't want to change the producer, just configure the consumer, if it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

Messages in the *_skipped* queue typically indicate a message type mismatch, most commonly caused by using different namespaces for the producer and the consumer.

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65887825/1882) and elsewhere, also highlighted in the [documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/messages.html).